Intersection of two sets of real numbers
If I have two sets:
$S_0 = \mathbb{R}$
$S_1 = \{ \frac{q}{5} : q \in \mathbb{R} \}$
I believe the intersection of these two sets is $\mathbb{R}$ still:
$S_0 \bigcap S_1 = \mathbb{R}$
Is this correct?

$S_0=S_1$ so their intersection is the same.

Good job. You are correct. Keep on progressing.
